# XML element change value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

the c# code as below:

```
using (XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(DocumentPath, XmlSettings))
{
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        switch (Reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                //doing function
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                if(Reader.Value.StartsWith("_"))
                {
                     // I want to replace the Reader.Value to new string
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                //doing function
                break;
            default:
                //doing function
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set the new value when XmlNodeType = text.

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem you're facing? What prevents you from doing the desired replace?

Comment: I don't know how to replace the value, because the Reader.Value is ReadOnly

Comment: Well, you are using a `..Reader`. If you want to **write** you would probably need a `..Writer`. Do you just want to overwrite the file again with a new value?

Comment: yes, just want to overwrite the file again with a new value. need to use XmlWriter to re-write whole xml??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 steps to this operations:

1. Load the document as an object model(XML is a hierarchy, if that makes it easier)
2. Alter the value in the object model
3. Resave the model as a file

The method of loading is up to you but i would recommend using `XDocument` and the related Linq-to-XML classes for smaller tasks like this. It is crazy easy [as demonstrated in this stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336983/update-xelement-value-in-xdocument)

*Edit - a useful quote for your scenario*

> XML elements can contain text content. Sometimes the content is simple
>   (the element only contains text content), and sometimes the content is
>   mixed (the contents of the element contains both text and other
>   elements). In either case, each chunk of text is represented as an
>   XText node.

From [MSDN - XText class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is a code sample for a console application using the xml from the comments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TextNodeChange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"<Info><title>a</title><content>texttexttexttexttext<tag>TAGNAME</tag>texttexttex‌​ttexttext</content>texttexttexttexttext</Info>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            Console.WriteLine("Input document");
            Console.WriteLine(doc);

            //get the all of the text nodes in the content element
            var textNodes = doc.Element("Info").Element("content").Nodes().OfType<XText>().ToList();

            //update the second text node
            textNodes[1].Value = "THIS IS AN ALTERED VALUE!!!!";

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Output document");
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Why are 3 steps required?**

Elements of xml are of variable length in a file. Altering a value may change the length of that part of the file and overwrite other parts. Therefore, you have to *deserialize* the whole document, make the changes and save it again.

Comment: Thx. but the xml structure is very strange. as: <Info><title>a</title><content>texttexttexttexttext<tag>TAGNAME</tag>texttexttexttexttext</content>texttexttexttexttext</info>, i dont know how to replace the "text" in XDocument

Comment: @CAM that xml sample would have been very useful at the beginning as i could have written a code sample. Xml allows mixed content of element nodes and raw text. This text is represented in the object model as a Text Element. Linq-to-XML defines this as `XText`. It will appear as one of the child nodes in the parent `XElement`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This information is very useful, thank you. but could you help to write a sample code??

Answer (score 0):

You cant replace the reader.value readonly property. You need to use XmlWriter to create your own xml and replace any value you want.